# React-native giving props through Tab navigator

Tags: react-native

i am trying to give props through a navigator.

This is what i have

```
export const NavigationMenu = ({ language, setLanguage }: props) => {
 return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <Tab.Navigator>
       <Tab.Screen name="Setting" component={SettingScreen}/>
       <Tab.Screen name="Input" component={Input}/>
     </Tab.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
 );
};
```

how do i add the language and setLanguage props to the tab screens?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by doing this:

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="Input"
    children={() => <Input language={language} />}
/>
```